# Where can I download the javadoc for swt(Only)

Tags: java, swt, jface

Does anyone know where I can download the javadoc files for Swt and/or JFace?

I do not want the api docs for the rest of Eclipse. I found a place where the docs are available for reading online but I really need them on my local computer.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the Eclipse **Classic Package** corresponding to your SWT / JFace versions from here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and then once unzipped and launched, just go to the Help -> Help Contents and then Platform Plugin Developer Guid, Reference, API Reference.

If you really need the html files, they are located in the plugins folder of your Eclipse SDK installation in the org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_XXXX.jar file.
If you open this file with 7Zip for example you will find the SWT Javadoc under: reference\api\org\eclipse\swt

I think it's the only way to get these html files

Comment: But extracting that .jar file gives me the docs for all of eclipse. I only need the swt/jface part and having all those other eclipse classes included is rather confusing. My use case is that I am developing an application with swt which don't have anything to do with eclipse. (So I am just using swf as gui library).

But I found a solution. I just downloaded the swt source and made the javadoc myself using the line


javadoc -source 1.4 -d docs -sourcepath . -link http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ -link . -subpackages org.eclipse.swt

Comment: @MTilsted- org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_XXXX.jar file does not contain a reference folder..!!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the SWT version you want, for the platform you're using, from the [SWT download page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).
2. Extract the zip file to a directory.
3. In the directory, there should be another zip file called src.zip. Extract *that* to another directory.
4. Delete any packages you don't want the javadocs for.
5. Use the javadoc utility that comes with the JDK to build the javadocs.

You only really need to do steps 3 to 5 if you're really low on disc space (which one hopes you're not, if it's your dev box!). A lot of IDEs, including [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) itself, will quite happily work with src.zip.

e.g. I copied src.zip to $MY_ECLIPSE_INSTALLATION_PATH/plugins/swt-4.2.2-gtk-linux-src.zip, and told Eclipse to look there for the SWT source. I now have easy access to the SWT javadocs (Eclipse creates them on the fly when I mouse over a SWT class name), so I no longer have to stumble around help.eclipse.org and its blasted `<title>`-hiding frames.

Answer (score 2):

No need to download externally. Install the 'Eclipse SDK' if you want JavaDoc for everything(including plugins) installed in Eclipse. The update site for this is download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4. (this is for eclipse juno. for kepler use version number 4.3 instead of 4.4). Go to Help>Install New Software> and give the above url for "work with" section. Then u will see the Eclipse sdk and u can install it. After installing it, after restarting eclipse all the docs support will be visible on your editor whenever u hover mouse on a special word. Trust me this is the easiest and 100% correct method. And installing this will configure the javadoc path for "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20140206-1358.jar" and "org.eclipse.swt_3.102.1.v20140206-1334.jar" which are visible in plugin dependencies of the project structure appropriately. The javadoc is actually modified at PATH_TO_ECLIPSE_FOLDER\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_4.3.0.v20130606-0003.jar in reference/api

Answer (score 1):

When you import, for example, SWT library in the project properties (Project properties ->Java Build Path->Libraries->add external jars ecc..)
add the library you need and then click on the little black arrow to expand the content. Click on **javadoc location** and set "Javadoc in archive" with these settings:

***archive path:***

PATH TO ECLIPSE FOLDER\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_4.3.0.v20130606-0003.jar

***path within archive:***

reference/api

This way you can click SHIFT-F2 on the method you want and go to the javadoc in eclipse.